# How does the compiler predefine the OS-specific preprocessors like __linux__, __apple__, etc.?

Tags: c++, c, preprocessor, conditional-compilation, predefined-macro

It's common to use the predefined preprocessors `__linux__` and `__apple__` for conditional compilation like this:

```
#if defined(__linux__)
inline void foo() {
    // Linux-specific implementation
}
#endif

#if defined(__apple__)
inline void foo() {
    // macOS-specific implementation
}
#endif

int main() {}
```

However, if I compile it with `clang main.cpp`, especially in case of cross-compilation, how does the compiler know which preprocessor should be predefined? `__linux__` or `__apple__` ?

Comment: The compiler knows which platform it's compiling for.

Comment: I don't specify the target platform in the compile command. How does the compiler know what platform I want?

Comment: I do not understand the question. The compiler does not "know" anything, the compiler was/is configured to compile for a specific platform.

Comment: Clang has a default target platform that you select when building Clang itself, you can see it in `clang --version` and override with `clang --target=??`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Even if I specified `--target=x86_64`, it may still be for macOS 
 rather than Linux.

Comment: I'm surprised `--target=x86_64` is even legal (I guess it's for baremetal?). They usually look like `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` (my desktop Linux), `x86_64-w64-windows-gnu` (MSYS2 MinGW), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the compiler knows the platform it is compiling to, and the target architecture is clear to the compiler, it will automatically feed those macros defined to the preprocessor, as if them had been included as `-D` parameters on the command line or an special *definitions file* had been inserted at the beginning of the source (*as if* means exactly that, you don't specify those parameters in the command line, but the compiler behaves as if those parameters had been specified at the start of the file)

You normally have an option to allow the compiler to show the whole set of automatic macro definitions it adds to the compilation unit before preprocessing.